# VSCodeでファイル保存時にPrettierのみを走らせたい

Tags: javascript, vscode, prettier

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Visual Studio Code(VSCode)でJavaScriptのファイルを保存した時に[Prettier](https://prettier.io/)のみを走らせたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ファイル保存時にPretterでフォーマットしたく、VSCodeの[Prettierの拡張](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)を入れ、`"editor.formatOnSave": true`に設定しています。

これで一応ファイルのフォーマットは行われるようになったのですが、リポジトリ内のESLintのAutoFixも同時に行われてしまい困っています。

[ESLintの拡張](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)が悪さをしているのかと思い、`"eslint.autoFixOnSave": false`を設定しても効きません。

#### 該当のソースコード

該当のリポジトリがこちらです https://github.com/pvcresin/es

#### 試したこと

現状は[ファイルを保存した時に任意のコマンドを走らせる拡張](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run)を使って、`prettier --write`を走らせて凌いでいます。

が、formatOnSaveから拡張経由でPrettierを動かすよりワンテンポ遅れて整形が走るので、できればPrettierとESLint以外の拡張に頼らずにできないかなと模索しています。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/213503

Comment: 英語版のstack overflowでも質問してみましたが、やはり難しいようです。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197173/i-want-to-run-only-prettier-when-saving-files-with-vscode/58362313#58362313